# Matplotlib - How to convert dates from SQLite to matplotlib format?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've dates from a SQLite table that I need to show in a matplotlib graphic as X.

```
"125","2013-08-30 13:33:11"
"120","2013-08-29 13:33:11"
"112","2013-08-28 13:33:11"
```

I need to use this dates i:

```
plt.plot(prices, dates)
```

How can I convert this date format to use it in a plot?

Best Regards,

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to covert the dates into `datetime` objects. To do this, use the `datetime.strptime` method with a format that fits your data. For example, you data is all of the form

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

for `year-month-day hour:min:sec`. Therefore, try something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import datetime as dt

raw_dates = ["2013-08-30 13:33:11", "2013-08-29 13:33:11", "2013-08-28 13:33:11"]
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in raw_dates]
y = [125, 120, 112]

plt.plot(x, y)
```

If you want to adjust the values on the x-axis (I think they will show up as hours), you can set a DateFormatter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import datetime as dt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

formatter = DateFormatter('%m-%d')

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

raw_dates = ["2013-08-30 13:33:11", "2013-08-29 13:33:11", "2013-08-28 13:33:11"]
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in raw_dates]
y = [125, 120, 112]
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

[image]